# vite react data-background in jsx not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I can't show images at react vite and also jquery.js and main.js index.html too

```
<SwiperSlide className="slider-bg d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" data-background="assets/img/slider/slider-bg-2.jpg">
```

can you help me solve this solution?

Comment: Have you checked if the image file path is correct and the image file itself?

Answer (score 0):

From the description I can only assume that you are not using `data-background` as a custom attribute and since I cannot find anything about `data-background` being anything but a custom attribute I can only assume it is not being used correctly. If you do not have a very imortant reason for using `data-background` I would suggest that you try this instead:

```
import importedPicture from './relative/path/to/picture.png'

<SwiperSlide className="slider-bg d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${importedPicture})` }}>
```